# Structured sampling in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there an easy way to enforce constraints on the selection of rows (samples) from the input and output with scikit-learn where sampling occurs; e.g., cross-validation, ensembling? I want to ensure that certain rows are selected as a batch (suppose they belong to the same group). In particular, I am hoping to be able to do this in the `Pipeline` framework (as a Transformation, perhaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cross-validation, there is [LeavePLabelOut](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LeavePLabelOut.html#sklearn.cross_validation.LeavePLabelOut) and [LeaveOneLabelOut](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneLabelOut.html#sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneLabelOut). For bootstrapping there is no such thing, but it will be possible (to implement) in the future.
Also see [the docs on cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/cross_validation.html#leave-one-label-out-lolo).